# Grignard Reagent Facilitates Epoxide Opening

Tags: hydrolysis, grignard-reagent, epoxidation

I have read from my textbook, that the opening of an epoxide ring with a strong nucleophile like a **Grignard reagent**, takes place from a **less substituted side**, with a **higher SN2 charact**er.

The **acidic workup** of the product obtained above gives **alcohol**.

Also, if ring-opening takes place in an acidic medium, it takes place with a higher **SN1 character** (even though carbocation formation doesn't really take place) and the epoxide ring opens from the **more substituted side**

My question is if one can protonate the epoxide in an acidic medium, then facilitate the reaction with Grignard Reagent (**RMgX**), would the regioselectivity be according to **SN2 type or SN1 type**, i.e. from the less substituted side, or more substituted side

I propose that since the epoxide ring is now protonated, it can easily leave than it's unprotonated form, and the Grignard Reagent can now attack from the more substituted side as well.

Edit:
The question I was talking of in the comments.

According to my teacher, the **H+ is the reminscent from the epoxidation reaction as benzoic acid is formed as a product**. I can see the the epoxide gets protonated, but the subsequent attack of Grignard Reagent is what confuses me

[image]

[image]

Answer given is A part, which corresponds to ring-opening from more substituted side.

Comment: Yeah, no, you can’t do that. Grignard plus acid do *not* go well together.

Comment: There are some nice examples of using Lewis acids + Grignards to control/change selectivity of ring opening. But as above, protic acids are a no go

Comment: I agree with you guy 1000%, even I understand acids turn Grignard reagents back to alkanes, the thing is, I have a question in my textbook which I have added in the edit above.

Comment: @Anmoldeep That H+ is most probably signifies acidic hydrolysis.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar But acidic hydrolysis of epoxides also requires a nucleophile, which is the Grignard reagent in the next step, which loops back onto my question, with what regioselectivity will the ring open

Comment: This looks like an error in the textbook. If the epoxide is protonated then the MeMgBr reacts with the proton to generate methane. As noted above lewis acids such as BF3 will bind to epoxides and enhamce their reactivity.

Comment: @Waylander, ok so there is no possibility of reaction here, MeMgBr even if in excess cannot open the epoxide?

Comment: If you use excess Grignard to neutralise all the H+ then eventually you will get Grignard attack on the epoxide, but why do it this way? You will get opening to give B and are using MeMgBr as a base, using up a costly reagent for no gain. If you want the epoxide opening to give A use BF3 as the complexing agent on the epoxide

Comment: @Waylander, thanks a tonne, I get it now